# Functors and Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

Let $\alpha$  be a functor from the category of groups in the category of groups which assigns to every group $G$ a characteristic subgroup $\alpha (G)$ of $G$ and to every homomorphism $\theta : H \rightarrow K$ the restriction  $\theta|_{\alpha(H)}:\alpha(H)\rightarrow \alpha(K)$ (in other words, $\alpha(H)^\theta \leq \alpha(K)$). So we have, in particular, that $\alpha(H)^\theta \leq \alpha(H^\theta)$. Is it true that also happen that $\alpha(H)^\theta$ is equal to  $\alpha(H^\theta)$? I think it holds, but why?

**References**

D.J.S. Robinson, "Finiteness Conditions and Generalized Soluble Groups", Vol. 1 Pag. 18, (1.3, at the bottom of the page)

Comment: There are many characteristic subgroups (e.g. all subgroups of $G$ is $G$ is cyclic), so $\alpha$ might make different "choices" for different $G$. Do I understand the statement right that the only restriction to these choices is that $\alpha(H)^\theta \le \alpha(K)$ for each homomorphism $\theta\colon H\to K$?

Comment: Yes, but I think that this isn't a real restriction since otherwise $\alpha$ could not be a functor assigning the restriction to each homomorphism.

Comment: Yes but you need this assumption (which is stronger than being characteristic!) in order to get a functor.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=173699 and http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=188277 are the papers of Baer mentioned. Baer appears to have switched from functor in the first to Robinson's definition in the second. Presumably Baer also found the equivalence obvious.

Comment: @JackSchmidt this is why I asked my question. It seems that both Robinson and Baer found the equivalence obvious. But to me is not so obvious :(. 
I "read" the paper of Baer but I cannot realize anything new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true at least for the category of Abelian groups. Take $\alpha (G)$ the subgroup of all elements of finite order. Set $H=\mathbb{Z}$ and $K=\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: But in this case: $\alpha(H)^i=[H,H]^i=\{1\}^i=\{1\}=[H^i,H^i]$ since $H$ and $H^i$ are both abelian (where $i$ is the identity function of $H$ in $K$). So this isn't a counterexample I think.

Comment: Sorry, I read the question wrong. I changed the answer.

Comment: The subgroup generated by the elements of finite order might work in general.

Comment: In your counterexample (following my notation) I think must be $K$ changed by $H$. Anyway it seems to work also in general. So the statment in Robinson's book is false?

Comment: I don't know, I have not this book.

Comment: @W4cc0: If it is any consolution (a) his books are excellent, (b) group theorists, and even module theorists, use the word functor in some very strange ways. Basically they mean “it behaves in some specific nice way compared to homomorphisms.” I found 6 or 7 different definitions of subgroup functor, none of which were similar enough to answer this question. It is pretty common to require equality in those definitions.

Comment: @JackSchmidt I know his books are really excellent ones; I just cannot sleep with a doubt. As matter (b), great! I was hoping such a thing! I see that it is something with which one must learn to deal. I'll look at that in this view. Thanks! 

Boris Novikov - Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at $\alpha(G)=G'$, the commutator subgroup, then it is true. In general [verbal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_subgroup) subgroup will do.

Comment: Yes but only the verbal subgroup will do this? This means that if $\alpha$ satisfies to my requirements then $\alpha$ is a "verbal" mapping?

Comment: Well, that is not clear. With respect to any variety of groups in any case you will have a lot of characteristic subgroups that are eligible, see for example http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Verbal_subgroup

Comment: Well, I know about verbal subgroup; my problem is the fact that Robinson in the text I cited says that: a group theoretical function (a function $\alpha$ assigning to each group $G$ a subgroup $\alpha(G)$ s.t. if $\theta : G \rightarrow K$ is an isomorphism of $G$ then $\alpha(G)^\theta=\alpha(G^\theta)$ is a functor of the category of groups if and only if for every homomorphism $\theta: G \rightarrow H$ it follows that $\alpha(G)^\theta=\alpha(G^\theta)$ - here the image of a homormorphism $G\rightarrow H$ under $\alpha$ is the restriction to $\alpha(G)$)

Comment: I proved that if the condition holds then $\alpha$ is a functor but I cannot see why if $\alpha$ is a functor the condition hold. If the condition hold then it can be proved that $\alpha$ is a "verbal" mapping.

@JackSchmidt Thanks, I removed it